# Not sure where to connect C wire on furnace

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I have a Nest 3rd gen thermostat running heat and AC and I even have an extra wire running to the thermostat (5 in all). One wire at the thermostat wiring box is available to use as the C wire, but I have no idea where to connect it. The box has different letters. See the images from my Nest - showing no power coming to RH. The white wire connected to the Nest G apparently isn't connected to anything so I can move that to C on the Nest, but where do I connect it on the furnace wiring box?

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What make/model is this "thermostat wiring box" of yours?

Comment: Honeywell and it says Aquastat Relay L8148E on the diagram on the inside of the cover.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the air handler please? That's a key missing link in this all...

Comment: Unfortunately the air handler is in the attic and not very accessible. I'll try to get up there later but aren't the red/white/blue wires running to the furnace, with the white wire not connected at the furnace at all?

Comment: It looks like you have one red/white/blue set running to the furnace and a second running to the air handler...are there any spare wires in the cable running to the air handler?

Comment: The red/white/blue wires are definitely in the same harness and the white wire - connected to G at the Nest - is not connected to anything. I know that's normally the fan but it must not be needed in my setup.

Comment: Yes, red/white/blue going to the furnace with the white unused. Can't get to the wiring at the handler yet. I was hoping the unused white wire at the furnace would help me - it's easier to get to the furnace.

Comment: Unfortunately, wiring to the furnace won't help you with a Nest as the Nest insists that the C wire come from the same transformer as Rc (*not* Rh)

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks all for the help. Looks like I'll have to call someone.

Comment: is there a wiring digram on the inside of the furnace cover - add a photo if there is,

Comment: Thanks Jasen - yes, I just added the picture of the wiring diagram from the cover.

Comment: Perchance, is sending the Nest back and getting a different thermostat an option?

Comment: When do you think you can get to the wiring at the air handler?

Comment: Sending the Nest back isn't an option but I wouldn't be totally against getting something different and using the Nest for another zone. I'll get to the air handler in the morning but I'm sure there are only 2 wires from there to the furnace.

Comment: @SFinch -- the question is about the wiring from the air-handler to the *thermostat*, as the air-handler will have its own 24VAC transformer in all likelihood

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I just posted a picture of the wiring in the air handler. If I'm understanding this better now, I should be able to move the white wire on G in the handler to C and the same in the Nest. I'd lose the fan control but I've seen that as a possible solution.

Comment: Where does the red? wire in the cable from the air-handler to the thermostat connect to at the air-handler end of things? (Perhaps a second photo with a different angle would help, even?)

Comment: The red/blue/white wires with the white arrows in the picture are in the same harness at the handler. The red/blue wires are connected to T/Y2 and the white is connected to G